# MySQL SELECT from field in CSV in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, csv

I am currently having issues with performing a MySQL SELECT Query based on rows in a .csv file inside a python script;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import MySQLdb, csv, sys

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="hostname",
                    user="user",
                    passwd="password",
                    db="database")


cur = db.cursor()

customers=csv.reader(file("customers.csv"))

for row in customers(row):
    cur.execute("select field from database.table where customernumber = %s;" % row)
    cur.commit()
    cur.close()
```

I am getting this;

```
    Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "script.py", line 17, in <module>
    cur.execute("select field from database.table where field = %s;" % row)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in        defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
   _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  '['1598']' at line 1")
```

The first row in the .csv file is 1598.

For some reason it is encasing this entry with `'['1598']'` hence the mySQL query failing,

Any ideas why it is encasing it and how to stop it?

Thanks in advance!

I have renamed all mysql details to defaults for DPA Reasons

Ashley

Comment: Why are you passing row in customers? customers(row)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to fix your csv reader logic. Then you need to pass the value as an argument to `execute`, `commit()` is done on the connection not the cursor and finally - you are closing your connection in the loop itself.

```
import csv

with open('customers.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rows = list(reader)

for row in rows:
    cur.execute("select field from database.table where customernumber = %s;", (row[0],))
    con.commit()

con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

for row in customers:
       print row , row[0]

row[0] should be first column value.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, the print works perfectly fine, print row prints the first as the mysql then kills the script, also row[0] works the same, both print same results as intended, but the mysql query is still having issues.

Comment: see line no. 1598 and try to edit and save the file again. Run the script. i think rest should be fine. above code should work. remove customers(row) in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change executing the SELECT to something like this:

```
cur.execute("SELECT field FROM database.table WHERE customernumber = %s", (row[0],))
```

If row[0] has the number, otherwise which ever index has it, like row[4].

Answer (score 0):

```
cur.execute("select field from database.table where customernumber = %s;" % row[0])
```

You need to pass `row[0]` instead of `row`. `row` is a list and `row[0]` is the first element of that list.